# Does it cost anything to list gs://?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

If I for example run scandir on a Google Cloud Storage Bucket folder on an App Engine Application, will this be billed?

I know it costs to connect to the bucket via the JSON and XML API, but I cannot find any info about the gs://.

If it costs anything, does scandir count as 1 class A operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), `storage.buckets.list` (listing buckets within a project) and `storage.objects.list` (listing objects within a bucket) are both Class A operations, which, as of today (July 16th, 2015) cost $0.01 per 1000 operations.

Comment: So your saying the gs:// protocol is equal to an API request?

Comment: `gs://` is a gsutil feature. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!